# Calculate total price, based on several input fields values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a form that contains several different products with different options to calculate and I need to get the total price.

Scenario:

```
(a+b) * c = price
(a+b) * c = price
(a+b) * c = price
```

`price` + `price` + `price` = `toltal`

This is my script, but it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").on("keyup", ".form-calc", function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest(".items");
        var sum = parent.find(".form-line").val((parent.find(".form-cost").val() + parent.find(".form-cost-skift").val()).toFixed(2));
        parent.find(".form-line").val((parent.find(".form-qty").val() * sum).toFixed(2));
        var total = 0;
        $(".form-line").each(function () {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
        });
        $("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pthv/tnzcz8a3/)

What I'm missing?

Comment: Console is saying one of your toFixed() is not a function

Comment: `(parent.find(".form-cost").val() + parent.find(".form-cost-skift").val()` is a string, it has not `toFixed` function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/tnzcz8a3/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").on("keyup", ".form-calc", function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest(".items");
        var sum = 0;
        var total = 0;

        if (!isNaN(parent.find(".form-cost").val())) sum += +parent.find(".form-cost").val();
        if (!isNaN(parent.find(".form-cost-skift").val())) sum += +parent.find(".form-cost-skift").val();
        if (!isNaN(parent.find(".form-qty").val())) sum *= +parent.find(".form-qty").val();

        parent.find(".form-line").val(sum.toFixed(2));

        $(".form-line").each(function () {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
        });

        $("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably a better way of doing !isNaN()

Comment: Hi Taplar.
That seems to do it. Thank you very much.

/Palle